# in magento 2 how to use existing customer attribute collection in my grid

Tags: magento2, grid

In magento 2 i am creating manage customer attribute grid. How can i use existing customer attribute collection in my module.
what will be my di.xml file?

Comment: Direct use of attribute collection not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need override customer file attribute  and need to entry in `di.xml` file

add dependency injection  in your custom module using `use keyword` and add dependency in contractor.